# reshape wide long with key specifying levels of grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset

```
structure(list(group = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"), 
    technique = c("attack", "defenese", "attack ", "defense ", 
    "defense ", "attack", "defense "), outcome1.part1 = c(24L, 
    1234L, 15L, 234L, 23L, 3L, 3L), outcome1.part.2 = c(52L, 
    321L, 23L, 234L, 234L, 145L, 145L), outcome1.part.3 = c(14L, 
    23L, 3L, 2L, 234L, 234L, 234L), outcome2.part.1 = c(14L, 
    234L, 145L, 4L, 234L, 145L, 145L), outcome2.part.2 = c(234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L), outcome2.part.3 = c(234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 145L, 145L, 145L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Dataset needs to be converted to long form but I want to make a vector that looks for any phrase from a specified key and then decides what level of a grouping variable will be assigned.

So say in column `outcome1.part.2` I want to convert this to long form and create a column called `strata` that uses whatever value from a key is found inside the column name. So the key would be `c("part.1", "part.2", "part.3")` and it will convert a row like this.

[image]

to this

[image]

I do not want to use regex solutions because I want to flexibly change the values in the key without figuring out a new regex solution for every level of the grouping variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
v1 <- c("part.1", "part.2", "part.3")
pat <- sprintf("^(outcome\\d*).*(%s).*$", str_c(v1, collapse="|"))
df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('outcome'), 
    names_to = c(".value", "strata"), 
     names_pattern = pat)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 21 × 5
   group technique  strata outcome1 outcome2
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <int>    <int>
 1 A     "attack"   part.1       24       14
 2 A     "attack"   part.2       52      234
 3 A     "attack"   part.3       14      234
 4 B     "defenese" part.1     1234      234
 5 B     "defenese" part.2      321      234
 6 B     "defenese" part.3       23      234
 7 A     "attack "  part.1       15      145
 8 A     "attack "  part.2       23      234
 9 A     "attack "  part.3        3      234
10 B     "defense " part.1      234        4
# … with 11 more rows
```

NOTE: There was a typo in the column names i.e. third column should be

```
names(df1)[3] <- 'outcome1.part.1'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a vector key though? For example, what if there are extraneous words after outcome that are not related to the level of interest? Like `outcome carnival part.1`. I only want part.1

Comment: @rj44 so you don't have digits after `outcome`?  then `names_pattern = "(outcome\\d*).*(part.*)"

Comment: Let me clarify, the words used in the key could be anything. it could be `outcome1 part.1` and I want `part.1`. another could be `outcome2 carnival tree`, but I only want `tree` to be the level in the grouping variable and ignore carnival. Does this make sense?

Comment: @rj44 so you need the first word and the last word?

Comment: @rj44 try the `names_pattern = "^(outcome\\d*).*(\\w+.*)$")` or `names_pattern = "^(outcome\\d*).*(\\w+\\d+?)$")`

Comment: Not exactly the first and last word. I'm aiming for a flexible less regex heavy solution that could even take something like a column name like `AF carnival dog pastry` and it's told to look at `AF` as the outcome and `dog` as the level of the value needed.

Comment: @rj44 do you have a set of words that should match based on position etc?  If the position and the words change everytime, it is difficult because there should be a pattern or matching to do this correctly

Comment: I'd prefer position agnostic solutions, but I'd like it to be a vector of character strings like this `c("part.1", "part.2", "part.3")`. This toy dataset is simpler than the very flexible goal I'm working towards where the vector could have a string like `c("asdf", "dsfg.uythwn", "dfgh")` and these are the levels searched for in the column names. If position is necessary, A solution where the columns all follow the convention `outcome_name.(the value needed)`  would also be something I could work with

Comment: @rj44 in the first vector `part` is common.  So, i would simply use `part\\d*`.  Is the second vector  the one in place of `part`? i.e. asdf, ...

Comment: @rj44 maybe you need the pattern as in the updated

Comment: Right, the second vector is one in place of part. The goal is to create a flexible solution that fits to multiple datasets without changing anything, but the vector basically. so that is why I want a key and not a regex solution for the values in part

Comment: @rj44 that is why i changed the part with creating a regex based on your input vector i.e. `v1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238814/discussion-between-rj44-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

A solution without regex, making use of the `extra = "merge"` argument in `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(id, group, technique)
  ) %>% 
  separate(name, into=c('outcome', 'strata'), extra = "merge") %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = outcome,
    values_from = value,
  ) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
   group technique  strata outcome1 outcome2
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <int>    <int>
 1 A     "attack"   part.1       24       14
 2 A     "attack"   part.2       52      234
 3 A     "attack"   part.3       14      234
 4 B     "defenese" part.1     1234      234
 5 B     "defenese" part.2      321      234
 6 B     "defenese" part.3       23      234
 7 A     "attack "  part.1       15      145
 8 A     "attack "  part.2       23      234
 9 A     "attack "  part.3        3      234
10 B     "defense " part.1      234        4
# ... with 11 more rows
```